# How to Split String Using Delimiters

Tags: python, string, split

I have a file called like so:

**test.txt**

```
dog;cat;mouse;bird;turtle;# just some animals
dog;cat;mouse;bird;turtle;horse cow # just some animals
```

I need help breaking up the second line so that it will look like the first line:

```
dog;cat;mouse;bird;turtle;horse;cow;# just some animals
```

The hard part is it has no set parameters on how many animal can be inserted between the 5th element and in front of the '#' symbol.  It could have 2 like I'm showing in this example or 10.

I'm able to break everything down to a two-dimensional array but not sure how to split the second string.

```
with open (file) as f:
    lines = list (f)
    temp = [line.strip ().split (';') for line in lines]
```

**Output:**

```
for i in temp:
    print (i)

['dog', 'cat', 'mouse', 'bird', 'turtle', '# just some animals']
['dog', 'cat', 'mouse', 'bird', 'turtle', 'horse cow # just some animals']
```

**Desired Output:**

```
['dog', 'cat', 'mouse', 'bird', 'turtle', '# just some animals']
['dog', 'cat', 'mouse', 'bird', 'turtle', 'horse', 'cow', '# just some animals']
```

Any help is appreciated.

**-Updated-**

My actual data contains the following pattern:

```
10-2-2015;10:02;LOCATION;xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;somename1 # more alphanumeric text with caps and lower case
10-2-2015;10:02;LOCATION;xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;somename1; somename2 somename3 # more,alphanumeric,text,with,caps,and,lower,case
```

The X's represents IPs and Subnet.  The commas after the '#' should be untouched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try a regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> my_expression = r'[a-z]+|#.+'
>>> f = 'dog;cat;mouse;bird;turtle;# just some animals'
>>> s = 'dog;cat;mouse;bird;turtle;horse cow # just some animals'
>>> re.findall(my_expression, f)
['dog', 'cat', 'mouse', 'bird', 'turtle', '# just some animals']
>>> re.findall(my_expression, s)
['dog', 'cat', 'mouse', 'bird', 'turtle', 'horse', 'cow', '# just some animals']
```

The above will find every instance of either a group of one or more lowercase letters (`[a-z]+`) or (`|`) a hash/pound sign followed by one or more characters (`#.+`).

For your updated sample data:

```
>>> my_expression = r'#.+|[^ ;]+'
>>> f='10-2-2015;10:02;LOCATION;xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;somename1 # more alphanumeric text with caps and lower case'
>>> s='10-2-2015;10:02;LOCATION;xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;somename1; somename2 somename3 # more,alphanumeric,text,with,caps,and,lower,case'
>>> my_expression = r'#.+|[^ ;]+'
>>> re.findall(my_expression, f)
['10-2-2015', '10:02', 'LOCATION', 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 'somename1', '# more alphanumeric text with caps and lower case']
>>> re.findall(my_expression, s)
['10-2-2015', '10:02', 'LOCATION', 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 'somename1', 'somename2', 'somename3', '# more,alphanumeric,text,with,caps,and,lower,case', '\n']
```

This expression looks for anything that is either a hash/pound sign followed by one or more characters (`#.+`) or (`|`) a group of one or more characters that are neither spaces nor semicolons (`[^ ;]+`).

Comment: This seems to do the trick; however, my data is slightly different.  I apologize.  I've updated my original question to reflect what I was hoping to accomplish.  I'm clueless at Regex and have spent good 2 hours trying to modify it to match my case with no luck so I'm hoping to find another solution without it.

Comment: @dreamzboy - Are your data delimited ONLY by semicolons, with no semicolons appearing in any actual field? Or also whitespace (or some other character) as in your original sample?

Comment: That's correct.  The delimiter is semicolon except for the last section where the "somename2" and "somename3" is delimited by white space.  I wanted to break that last 2 or possibly more "somename" to their own element.

Comment: @dreamzboy - I've added a different expression that will capture your updated sample data.

Comment: I guess regular expression it is.  Thanks to your detailed explanation, I now know Greek.  Very clever how you use the "not" (^) group.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Find the index of # and remove everything after that, inclusive, from the string. Then, Find any whitespace (and/or any other desired characters) and make it a semicolon.

Comment: That's great but do you have a working code to show?  I have my own method too but it's really ugly.